# Hide rows in an already filtered ranged based on two conditions for two different columns

Tags: excel, vba, range, filtering

I know how to do this with one condition, in fact I am already using it in my macro:

```
Dim cl, dl As Range, LR As Long, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
LR = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cl In ws.Range("AK2:AK" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
     If cl.Value < 10 Then cl.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Next cl
```

Next, I would need to hide some more rows but based on two criteria this time.
If column AL contains the value PASS, then I need to look at column H and hide all the rows that have a value different from 1 there. Is this even possible? I tried to define a second range called dl, but it does not work. Below two of my unsuccessful attempts. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
LR = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cl In ws.Range("AL2:AL" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If cl.Value = "PASS" Then Set dl = ws.Range("H2:H" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
       If dl.Value <> 1 Then dl.EntireRow.Hidden = True
       End If
Next cl
```

```
LR = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each cl In ws.Range("H2:H" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set dl = ws.Range("AL2:AL" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If dl.Value = "PASS" And cl.Value = 1 Then cl.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Next cl
```

Comment: (Looking at your first attempt): It looks like you need a nested `For Each` for the `dl` `Range`: you loop over the `cl` `Range` but then you only set `dl` to be the entire `Range` - and you're trying to check the `Value` of that. Try looping through that second `ws.Range` as you did for the first one, but within the `"PASS"` condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `cl.Row` to refer to the cell in column H in the same row as `cl`.

```
For Each cl In ws.Range("AL2:AL" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
     If cl.Value = "PASS" And ws.Cells(cl.Row, "H").Value <> 1 Then 
          cl.EntireRow.Hidden = True
     End If
Next cl
```

Comment: "For Each cl In ws.Range("AL2:AL" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)" but otherwise works like a charm ;) (I did previously filter by AK for a different value, thought I was going crazy for a bit as my macro wasn't working :D)
the dataset is filtered down from 13k lines to around 50-60 maximum at this point so this definitely does the trick

Comment: Oops copied the wrong line of code, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

### Hide Rows

- This might be too slow on a large dataset. Introducing `AutoFilter` would make it more efficient and useful.
- I'm not sure why you would use `SpecialCells` for the 1st condition though.
- These will apply all three criteria at once.

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Sub HideRowsQF()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim rg As Range:
    Set rg = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    If rg.Row < 2 Then Exit Sub ' no data: A2-->2
    
    Set rg = rg.EntireRow.Columns("AK")
    rg.EntireRow.Hidden = False ' show all
    
    Dim cl As Range, HideRow As Boolean
    
    For Each cl In rg.Cells
        If cl.Value < 10 Then
            HideRow = True
        ElseIf ws.Cells(cl.Row, "AL").Value = "PASS" Then
            If ws.Cells(cl.Row, "H").Value <> 1 Then HideRow = True
        End If
        If HideRow Then HideRow = False: cl.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next cl

End Sub
```

**An Improvement**

- Introduced `Application.ScreenUpdating` and `Application.Union`.

```vb
Sub HideRows()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim rg As Range, rCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range("A2")
        .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, .Column).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        rCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp) - .Row + 1
        If rCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data
        Set rg = .Resize(rCount)
    End With
    
    Set rg = rg.EntireRow.Columns("AK")
    
    Dim cl As Range, HideRow As Boolean
    
    For Each cl In rg.Cells
        If cl.Value < 10 Then
            HideRow = True
        ElseIf ws.Cells(cl.Row, "AL").Value = "PASS" Then
            If ws.Cells(cl.Row, "H").Value <> 1 Then HideRow = True
        End If
        If HideRow Then
            HideRow = False
            If urg Is Nothing Then Set urg = cl Else Set urg = Union(urg, cl)
        End If
    Next cl
    
    If Not urg Is Nothing Then urg.EntireRow.Hidden = True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Rows hidden.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```